# Delete deployment from Azure Subscription using Azure Cli

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli

I am trying to delete the deployments from a given resource group (because it hits the max 800) via Azure Cli as below. But the script below doesnt work. Does anyone have any idea?

```
az Login
az account set --subscription "mysubscription"
$resourceGroupName = "myresourcegroup"
$deployments = az group deployment list --resource-group $resourceGroupName
Foreach ($deployment in $deployments)
{
    az group deployment delete --name $deployment.name --resource-group $resourceGroupName
}
```

-Alan-

Comment: What the means not work? Did you get any error  message？ I test in my site and work well.

Comment: @JoeyCai , this is the error. z : ERROR: az group deployment delete: error: argument --name/-n: expected one argument
At line:8 char:5
+     az group deployment delete --name $deployment.name --resource-group $resourc ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: az group...ed one argument:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Answer (score 0):

This happens because az cli outputs a json, not an object. you need to cast it to object for this to work:

```bsh
$deployments = ( az group deployment list --resource-group $resourceGroupName ) |
    ConvertFrom-Json
Foreach ($deployment in $deployments) {
    az group deployment delete --name $deployment.name --resource-group $resourceGroupName
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error for the above. 
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid array passed in, ']' expected. (1): [
At line:5 char:83
+ ... eGroupName ) | ConvertFrom-Json
+                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand

Comment: just examine what the `az group deployment list` returns, if, for some reason, it doesnt return json, you can force it to do that with `-o json`. by default it returns json

Comment: It does return json

Comment: well, then you mistyped the command, i bet you forgot the `()`